# Redirect 301 - htaccess or plugin?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

after a migration from a custom cms to WordPress I have about 1500 404 errors.
The old cms used to print the date into the post url and I have removed that and set a proper SEO url structure.

Now, since I need to create 301 redirect for all of them, each one by one, what is the best practice?
Should I insert them all into the htaccess file or managing them with a plugin?

Will all these redirections slow down the website?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions will work but

1) .htaccess will have the best redirect speed because it is not part of WP.

2) Plugin will allow to use wp interface for editing but redirect a little bit slower (not critical)

Usually redirects don't slow down website speed tangibly